# ListFragment Load more on scroll end

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

I have for my ListFragment and was wondering what the best way to load more content within the list when I reach the bottom, I believe I need to implement a Scroll Listener but I was a little confused on where and when to have the call performed, if someone can shed some light that would be much appreciated, I know my codes a tad bit messy right now too since I am just testing this out, so apologies for that.

Code: 
**TestListFragment**

```
package com.fragments;

public class TestListFragment extends ListFragment
        implements
        android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<TestItemModel>> {

    TestCustomArrayAdapter _adapter;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        System.out.println("TestListFragment.onActivityCreated");

        // Initially there is no data
        setEmptyText("Refresh: No Data Here");

        // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
        _adapter = new TestCustomArrayAdapter(getActivity());
        setListAdapter(_adapter);

        // Start out with a progress indicator.
        setListShown(false);

        // Prepare the loader. Either re-connect with an existing one,
        // or start a new one.
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Insert desired behavior here.
        Log.i("TestListFragment", "Item clicked: " + id);
        TestItemModel ti = this._adapter.getItem(position);
        System.out.println(ti.getId());

    }

    @Override
    public Loader<List<TestItemModel>> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        System.out.println("TestListFragment.onCreateLoader");
        return new TestListLoaderAsync(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<TestItemModel>> arg0,
            List<TestItemModel> data) {
        _adapter.setData(data);
        System.out.println("TestListFragment.onLoadFinished");
        // The list should now be shown.
        if (isResumed()) {
            setListShown(true);
        } else {
            setListShownNoAnimation(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<TestItemModel>> arg0) {
        _adapter.setData(null);
    }

}
```

**TestCustomArrayAdapter**

```
package com.adapters;

public class TestCustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TestItemModel> {
    private final LayoutInflater _inflater;
    public OnItemClickListener _ol;
    public ImageLoader _imageLoader;

    public TestCustomArrayAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.test_list_fragment);
        _inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // Load up Image Loader
        _imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);

    }

    public void setData(List<TestItemModel> data) {
        clear();
        if (data != null) {
            for (TestItemModel appEntry : data) {
                add(appEntry);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Populate new items in the list.
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // create viewHolder
        View view;

        // Check Views
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_single_item, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        // Create Items
        TestItemModel item = getItem(position);

        TextView itemLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_label);
        TextView itemId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_id);

        // Create ImageViews
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_id);

        // Create Buttons
        Button btn1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_id_1);
        Button btn2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_id_2);
        Button btn3 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_id_3);

        // Create Resources
        Resources resources = this.getContext().getResources();

        // Create Listeners
        _ol = new OnItemClickListener(position, item);

        // Setup TextViews
        itemLabel.setText(item.getName());
        itemId.setText(item.getName());

        // Setup Images
        _imageLoader.DisplayImage(item.getBm(), image);

        // Setup Buttons
        btn1.setOnClickListener(_ol);
        btn1.setTag(1);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(_ol);
        btn2.setTag(2);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(_ol);
        btn3.setTag(3);

        return view;
    }

    private class OnItemClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        private int _position;
        private TestItemModel _testItem;

        public OnItemClickListener(int position, TestItemModel ti) {
            _position = position;
            _testItem = ti;
        }

        // TODO
        // provide functionality for which button was clicked then pass the item
        // to which it was clicked in.
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_id_1:
                // btn1 clicked
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                        " Button1 clicked at positon" + v.getTag(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.button_id_2:
                // btn2 clicked
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                        " Button2 clicked at positon" + v.getTag(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.button_id_3:
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                        " Button3 clicked at positon" + v.getTag(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // btn 3 clciked
                break;
            }

            // the view is the button, so you get get the tag it has set with
            // v.getTag() to know what button is pressed.
            Log.v("YOOO",
                    "Button Click at position " + _position + " " + v.getTag()
                            + " Item ID = " + _testItem.getId());

        }
    }

}
```

**TestListLoaderAsync**

package com.tasks;

public class TestListLoaderAsync extends AsyncTaskLoader> {

```
private List<TestItemModel> _models;

// Test URLS
private final String[] URLS = {
        "http://www.pressurewasherparts.com.au/upimages/image/Water_Broom/Water%20Broom%203%20Noz%20upright.jpg",
        "http://www.pressurewasherparts.com.au/upimages/image/Water_Broom/Water%20Broom%203%20Noz%20upright.jpg",
        "http://lh3.ggpht.com/_GEnSvSHk4iE/TDSfmyCfn0I/AAAAAAAAF8Y/cqmhEoxbwys/s144-c/_MG_3675.jpg",
        "http://lh6.ggpht.com/_Nsxc889y6hY/TBp7jfx-cgI/AAAAAAAAHAg/Rr7jX44r2Gc/s144-c/IMGP9775a.jpg",
        "http://lh3.ggpht.com/_lLj6go_T1CQ/TCD8PW09KBI/AAAAAAAAQdc/AqmOJ7eg5ig/s144-c/Juvenile%20Gannet%20despute.jpg",
        "http://lh6.ggpht.com/_ZN5zQnkI67I/TCFFZaJHDnI/AAAAAAAABVk/YoUbDQHJRdo/s144-c/P9250508.JPG",
        "http://lh4.ggpht.com/_XjNwVI0kmW8/TCOwNtzGheI/AAAAAAAAC84/SxFJhG7Scgo/s144-c/0014.jpg",
        "http://lh6.ggpht.com/_lnDTHoDrJ_Y/TBvKsJ9qHtI/AAAAAAAAG6g/Zll2zGvrm9c/s144-c/000007.JPG",
        "http://lh6.ggpht.com/_qvCl2efjxy0/TCIVI-TkuGI/AAAAAAAAOUY/vbk9MURsv48/s144-c/DSC_0844.JPG",
        "http://lh4.ggpht.com/_TPlturzdSE8/TBv4ugH60PI/AAAAAAAAMsI/p2pqG85Ghhs/s144-c/_MG_3963.jpg",
        "http://lh4.ggpht.com/_4f1e_yo-zMQ/TCe5h9yN-TI/AAAAAAAAXqs/8X2fIjtKjmw/s144-c/IMG_1786.JPG",
        "http://lh6.ggpht.com/_iFt5VZDjxkY/TB9rQyWnJ4I/AAAAAAAADpU/lP2iStizJz0/s144-c/DSCF1014.JPG",
        "http://lh5.ggpht.com/_hepKlJWopDg/TB-_WXikaYI/AAAAAAAAElI/715k4NvBM4w/s144-c/IMG_0075.JPG",
        "http://lh6.ggpht.com/_OfRSx6nn68g/TCzsQic_z3I/AAAAAAABOOI/5G4Kwzb2qhk/s144-c/EASTER%20ISLAND_Hanga%20Roa_31.5.08_46.JPG",
        "http://lh6.ggpht.com/_ZGv_0FWPbTE/TB-_GLhqYBI/AAAAAAABVxs/cVEvQzt0ke4/s144-c/IMG_1288_hf.jpg",
        "http://lh6.ggpht.com/_a29lGRJwo0E/TBqOK_tUKmI/AAAAAAAAVbw/UloKpjsKP3c/s144-c/31012332.jpg",
        "http://lh3.ggpht.com/_55Lla4_ARA4/TB6xbyxxJ9I/AAAAAAABTWo/GKe24SwECns/s144-c/Bluebird%20049.JPG",
        "http://lh3.ggpht.com/_iVnqmIBYi4Y/TCaOH6rRl1I/AAAAAAAA1qg/qeMerYQ6DYo/s144-c/Kwiat_100626_0016.jpg",
        "http://lh6.ggpht.com/_QFsB_q7HFlo/TCItd_2oBkI/AAAAAAAAFsk/4lgJWweJ5N8/s144-c/3705226938_d6d66d6068_o.jpg",
        "http://lh5.ggpht.com/_JTI0xxNrKFA/TBsKQ9uOGNI/AAAAAAAChQg/z8Exh32VVTA/s144-c/CRW_0015-composite.jpg",
        "http://lh6.ggpht.com/_loGyjar4MMI/S-InVNkTR_I/AAAAAAAADJY/Fb5ifFNGD70/s144-c/Moving%20Rock.jpg",
        "http://lh4.ggpht.com/_L7i4Tra_XRY/TBtxjScXLqI/AAAAAAAAE5o/ue15HuP8eWw/s144-c/opera%20house%20II.jpg",
        "http://lh3.ggpht.com/_rfAz5DWHZYs/S9cstBTv1iI/AAAAAAAAeYA/EyZPUeLMQ98/s144-c/DSC_6425.jpg",
        "http://lh6.ggpht.com/_iGI-XCxGLew/S-iYQWBEG-I/AAAAAAAACB8/JuFti4elptE/s144-c/norvig-polar-bear.jpg",
        "http://lh3.ggpht.com/_M3slUPpIgmk/SlbnavqG1cI/AAAAAAAACvo/z6-CnXGma7E/s144-c/mf_003.jpg",
        "http://lh4.ggpht.com/_loGyjar4MMI/S-InQvd_3hI/AAAAAAAADIw/dHvCFWfyHxQ/s144-c/Rainbokeh.jpg",
        "http://lh4.ggpht.com/_yy6KdedPYp4/SB5rpK3Zv0I/AAAAAAAAOM8/mokl_yo2c9E/s144-c/Point%20Reyes%20road%20.jpg",
        "http://lh5.ggpht.com/_6_dLVKawGJA/SMwq86HlAqI/AAAAAAAAG5U/q1gDNkmE5hI/s144-c/mobius-glow.jpg",
        "http://lh3.ggpht.com/_QFsB_q7HFlo/TCItc19Jw3I/AAAAAAAAFs4/nPfiz5VGENk/s144-c/4551649039_852be0a952_o.jpg",
        "http://lh6.ggpht.com/_TQY-Nm7P7Jc/TBpjA0ks2MI/AAAAAAAABcI/J6ViH98_poM/s144-c/IMG_6517.jpg",
        "http://lh3.ggpht.com/_rfAz5DWHZYs/S9cLAeKuueI/AAAAAAAAeYU/E19G8DOlJRo/s144-c/DSC_4397_8_9_tonemapped2.jpg",
        "http://lh4.ggpht.com/_TQY-Nm7P7Jc/TBpi6rKfFII/AAAAAAAABbg/79FOc0Dbq0c/s144-c/david_lee_sakura.jpg",
        "http://lh3.ggpht.com/_TQY-Nm7P7Jc/TBpi8EJ4eDI/AAAAAAAABb0/AZ8Cw1GCaIs/s144-c/Hokkaido%20Swans.jpg",
        "http://lh3.ggpht.com/_1aZMSFkxSJI/TCIjB6od89I/AAAAAAAACHM/CLWrkH0ziII/s144-c/079.jpg",
        "http://lh5.ggpht.com/_loGyjar4MMI/S-InWuHkR9I/AAAAAAAADJE/wD-XdmF7yUQ/s144-c/Colorado%20River%20Sunset.jpg",
        "http://lh3.ggpht.com/_0YSlK3HfZDQ/TCExCG1Zc3I/AAAAAAAAX1w/9oCH47V6uIQ/s144-c/3138923889_a7fa89cf94_o.jpg",
        "http://lh6.ggpht.com/_K29ox9DWiaM/TAXe4Fi0xTI/AAAAAAAAVIY/zZA2Qqt2HG0/s144-c/IMG_7100.JPG",
        "http://lh6.ggpht.com/_0YSlK3HfZDQ/TCEx16nJqpI/AAAAAAAAX1c/R5Vkzb8l7yo/s144-c/4235400281_34d87a1e0a_o.jpg",
        "http://lh4.ggpht.com/_8zSk3OGcpP4/TBsOVXXnkTI/AAAAAAAAAEo/0AwEmuqvboo/s144-c/yosemite_forrest.jpg",
        "http://lh4.ggpht.com/_6_dLVKawGJA/SLZToqXXVrI/AAAAAAAAG5k/7fPSz_ldN9w/s144-c/coastal-1.jpg",
        "http://lh4.ggpht.com/_WW8gsdKXVXI/TBpVr9i6BxI/AAAAAAABhNg/KC8aAJ0wVyk/s144-c/IMG_6233_1_2-2.jpg",
        "http://lh3.ggpht.com/_loGyjar4MMI/S-InS0tJJSI/AAAAAAAADHU/E8GQJ_qII58/s144-c/Windmills.jpg",
        "http://lh4.ggpht.com/_loGyjar4MMI/S-InbXaME3I/AAAAAAAADHo/4gNYkbxemFM/s144-c/Frantic.jpg",
        "http://lh5.ggpht.com/_loGyjar4MMI/S-InKAviXzI/AAAAAAAADHA/NkyP5Gge8eQ/s144-c/Rice%20Fields.jpg",
        "http://lh3.ggpht.com/_loGyjar4MMI/S-InZA8YsZI/AAAAAAAADH8/csssVxalPcc/s144-c/Seahorse.jpg",
        "http://lh3.ggpht.com/_syQa1hJRWGY/TBwkCHcq6aI/AAAAAAABBEg/R5KU1WWq59E/s144-c/Antelope.JPG",
        "http://lh5.ggpht.com/_MoEPoevCLZc/S9fHzNgdKDI/AAAAAAAADwE/UAno6j5StAs/s144-c/c84_7083.jpg",
        "http://lh4.ggpht.com/_DJGvVWd7IEc/TBpRsGjdAyI/AAAAAAAAFNw/rdvyRDgUD8A/s144-c/Free.jpg",
        "http://lh6.ggpht.com/_iO97DXC99NY/TBwq3_kmp9I/AAAAAAABcz0/apq1ffo_MZo/s144-c/IMG_0682_cp.jpg",
        "http://lh4.ggpht.com/_7V85eCJY_fg/TBpXudG4_PI/AAAAAAAAPEE/8cHJ7G84TkM/s144-c/20100530_120257_0273-Edit-2.jpg" };

public TestListLoaderAsync(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public List<TestItemModel> loadInBackground() {

    System.out.println("TestListLoader.loadInBackground");

    // You should perform the heavy task of getting data from
    // Internet or database or other source
    // Here, we are generating some Sample data

    // Create corresponding array of entries and load with data.
    List<TestItemModel> entries = new ArrayList<TestItemModel>(5);
    entries.add(new TestItemModel("Java", "1", URLS[1]));
    entries.add(new TestItemModel("C++", "2", URLS[2]));
    entries.add(new TestItemModel("Python", "3", URLS[3]));
    entries.add(new TestItemModel("JavaScript", "4", URLS[4]));
    entries.add(new TestItemModel("D", "5", URLS[5]));
    entries.add(new TestItemModel("C", "6", URLS[6]));
    entries.add(new TestItemModel("Perl", "7", URLS[7]));
    entries.add(new TestItemModel("Fortran", "8", URLS[8]));
    entries.add(new TestItemModel("Cobalt", "9", URLS[9]));
    entries.add(new TestItemModel("Ruby", "10", URLS[10]));
    entries.add(new TestItemModel("Pascal", "11", URLS[11]));
    entries.add(new TestItemModel("HTML", "12", URLS[12]));
    entries.add(new TestItemModel("CSS", "13", URLS[13]));
    entries.add(new TestItemModel("PHP", "14", URLS[14]));
    entries.add(new TestItemModel("MYSQL", "15", URLS[15]));
    entries.add(new TestItemModel("Fortran", "8", URLS[16]));
    entries.add(new TestItemModel("Cobalt", "9", URLS[17]));
    entries.add(new TestItemModel("Ruby", "10", URLS[18]));
    entries.add(new TestItemModel("Pascal", "11", URLS[19]));
    entries.add(new TestItemModel("HTML", "12", URLS[20]));
    entries.add(new TestItemModel("CSS", "13", URLS[21]));
    entries.add(new TestItemModel("PHP", "14", URLS[22]));
    entries.add(new TestItemModel("MYSQL", "15", URLS[23]));

    TestItemModel lastItem = new TestItemModel("C#", "16", URLS[0]);

    lastItem.setId("TestingId");
    entries.add(lastItem);

    return entries;
}

/**
 * Called when there is new data to deliver to the client. The super class
 * will take care of delivering it; the implementation here just adds a
 * little more logic.
 */
@Override
public void deliverResult(List<TestItemModel> listOfData) {
    if (isReset()) {
        // An async query came in while the loader is stopped. We
        // don't need the result.
        if (listOfData != null) {
            onReleaseResources(listOfData);
        }
    }
    List<TestItemModel> oldApps = listOfData;
    _models = listOfData;

    if (isStarted()) {
        // If the Loader is currently started, we can immediately
        // deliver its results.
        super.deliverResult(listOfData);
    }

    // At this point we can release the resources associated with
    // 'oldApps' if needed; now that the new result is delivered we
    // know that it is no longer in use.
    if (oldApps != null) {
        onReleaseResources(oldApps);
    }
}

/**
 * Handles a request to start the Loader.
 */
@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
    if (_models != null) {
        // If we currently have a result available, deliver it
        // immediately.
        deliverResult(_models);
    }

    if (takeContentChanged() || _models == null) {
        // If the data has changed since the last time it was loaded
        // or is not currently available, start a load.
        forceLoad();
    }
}

/**
 * Handles a request to stop the Loader.
 */
@Override
protected void onStopLoading() {
    // Attempt to cancel the current load task if possible.
    cancelLoad();
}

/**
 * Handles a request to cancel a load.
 */
@Override
public void onCanceled(List<TestItemModel> apps) {
    super.onCanceled(apps);

    // At this point we can release the resources associated with 'apps'
    // if needed.
    onReleaseResources(apps);
}

/**
 * Handles a request to completely reset the Loader.
 */
@Override
protected void onReset() {
    super.onReset();

    // Ensure the loader is stopped
    onStopLoading();

    // At this point we can release the resources associated with 'apps'
    // if needed.
    if (_models != null) {
        onReleaseResources(_models);
        _models = null;
    }
}

/**
 * Helper function to take care of releasing resources associated with an
 * actively loaded data set.
 */
protected void onReleaseResources(List<TestItemModel> apps) {
}
```

}

Comment: Here's a great solution for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20458604/2082668

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onScrollListener has a lot of useful info that you can use.  Here is what I did with a GridView (same listener as a ListView).  All of the variables are ints.  I calculated a read ahead point using the available info.

```
   mGridView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (visibleItemCount > 0) {

                // First time: init read ahead variables
                if (mPageSize == 0) {
                    mPageSize = visibleItemCount;
                    mReadAheadSize = mPageSize * 2;
                    mRATrigger = visibleItemCount + mReadAheadSize;
                }

                int lastVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
                int lastRAItem = lastVisibleItem + mReadAheadSize;

                if (lastRAItem >= mRATrigger) {
                      // At read-ahead point.  Reset to next read-ahead point and call
                      // call a method to add more items to the ListView.
                }
```

Comment: I made a scrollListener similar to this and set my ListView to this as well similarly, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can trigger the "load more" event when the position in getView in your adapter reaches the last position!

Comment: I see what you mean, can you provide an example snippet of use?