# Android - ListView to load more items when reached end

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have successfully implemented a listView where each row is an object I've created.
I have an interface which reads some objects and returns an array of them, which I pass to the adapter constructor.
What I want to do is, since the list may be very long, My interface allows to read each time some more items (page 0, page 1...) so I Want, when the user reaches the last row of the list, load the next page and insert it to the listView.
What is the proper way of doing so?
I actually want the "reach end of list" trigger a callback where I can request for more pages and load them to the list.
A bit OT to my main question, But I dont mind using a baseAdapter, both would work, I just dont know what's better for the task.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can add a footer on the listView which will have a button named LoadMore. Here is a complete tutorial [ListView with Load More Button](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/) 
 Or you can implement onscrolllistener() and add this listener to your ListView

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    this.currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
    this.currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
}

public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    this.currentScrollState = scrollState;
    this.isScrollCompleted();
 }

private void isScrollCompleted() {
    if (this.currentVisibleItemCount > 0 && this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        /*** In this way I detect if there's been a scroll which has completed ***/
        /*** do the work for load more date! ***/
        if(!isLoading){
             isLoading = true;
             loadMoreData();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will help

Comment: thank you, I'll try this and see how it turns out :)

Comment: Why not use java.util.concurrent.Semaphore to make things even more solid ?

Comment: @Md. Monsur Hossain Tonr where is the class for onScrollListener

Comment: where we have to make `isLoading` false?

Comment: @pRaNaY You are supposed to reset `isLoading` after `loadMoreData()` completed.