# Listview Height issue inside ScrollView in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am using `ListView` inside `ScrollView` in Android. So, as we all know, It will occur height issue. For that, I am setting `ListView` size using below code :

```
public static void getListViewSize(ListView myListView, Context context) {
        ListAdapter myListAdapter = myListView.getAdapter();

        if (myListAdapter == null) {
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {

            View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, myListView);
            if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup)
                listItem.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
            int listViewWidth = screenWidth - 65;
            int widthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listViewWidth,
                    MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            listItem.measure(widthSpec, 0);

            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight
                + (myListView.getDividerHeight() * (myListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        myListView.setLayoutParams(params);
        myListView.requestLayout();
    }
```

**Xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvHomeStream"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="#b5b5b5"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMoreRecords"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/list"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/viewmore"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

It works fine if height of each ListView item is same. But, if height of each `ListView` item is unusual, then it leave extra big space between `ListView` end boundary and `TextView`.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: this is not your answer but it's not a good way to put `listView` inside the `ScrollView`

Comment: listview is already a scrollview

Comment: For your requirement, put that textview with id tvMoreRecords in footer view of listview , so you will not have the requirement of listview inside scrollview.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan, then how should i use it ?

Comment: @RaviBhatt, i knw but that way, it will show `TextView` at fix position which I dont want.

Comment: @Saqib, I know about it.

Comment: what you want to do exactly?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan, I want to show `TextView` exact below of ListView and without any extra space.

Comment: @JeetenParmar Adding footer view do the same.

Comment: you can add your TextView as a final row to your ListView, but for this purpose you need right custom adapter

Comment: @JeetenParmar your question is  totally different with your accepted answer.

Comment: @DevCarlsberg, read my question properly, specially after xml part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Dev Carlsberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1868262/dev-carlsberg) suggested **DONT USE** `ListView` inside `ScrollView` you can change the xml to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMoreRecords"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/list"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/viewmore"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvHomeStream"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

or alternatively you may find the

[Android ListView with Load More Button](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/)

[Android - ListView to load more items when reached end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458475/android-listview-to-load-more-items-when-reached-end)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Android ListView with Load More Button, this has solved my issue as per my requirement.

Answer (score 9):

ok i share my project code here may be it helps you..

This class calculate the height and automatically adjust the layoutparams.

### Solution:-

```
 package com.kview;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.util.AttributeSet;
 import android.widget.GridView;
 import android.widget.ListView;

 public class FullLengthListView extends ListView {

boolean expanded = true;

public FullLengthListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defaultStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defaultStyle);
}

public FullLengthListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public boolean isExpanded() {
    return expanded;
}

public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
    this.expanded = expanded;
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
    if (isExpanded()) {
        // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
        // View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    } else {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
  }
```

Comment: HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!   =0

Comment: Very good. Just need to use FullLengthListView in xml and in Java code.

Comment: it works like a charm. easy and elegant solution. bravo!

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good practice to put a listview in scrollView.and if put the listview inside the scroll then the height of the listview is a measure issue. you have to fix the height of  listview.and to scroll both listview and scroll view your have to set the touch listner on listview,like:

```
listview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

now,when you touch the listview,it will disable the scroll of scroll view and your listview will work.else  when you touch on other part of screen then scroll view will work smoothly.only this the possible solution.

## Update

now your an use recyclerview, since 23.0.2 support lib, it supports wrap_content height too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then, how can I load data automatically when user go from up to down in activity ???

Comment: you just have to set the adpater dude,and fix the height of listview.thats it.if your are using any other type of listview then also you have to set the adapter onlu,here issue is height of the listview in scrollview and also one more issue scrollview inside scroll becuse listview parent class is scrollview.hjust fix the height and you will get everything you want

Answer (score 1):

It is the best answer to your question and it is provided by **Romain Guy**.
(the *father* of ListView)

[How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing/3496042#3496042)

You should use a `LinearLayout` instead of your `ListView`.
Something like this:

```
public class MyListLayout extends LinearLayout implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    private Adapter list;
    private View.OnClickListener mListener;

    public MyListLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyListLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }

    public MyListLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mListener!=null)
            mListener.onClick(v);
    }

    public void setList(Adapter list) {
        this.list = list;

        //Popolute list
        if (this.list!=null){
            for (int i=0;i<this.list.getCount();i++){
                View item= list.getView(i, null,null);
                this.addView(item);
            }
        }

    }

    public void setmListener(View.OnClickListener mListener) {
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }
}
```