# How to implement endless scrolling listview

Tags: android, json, android-listview, endlessscroll

I am creating an application in which I am parsing data using Json parsing. I've implemented listview and in my response i have `totalpage` and `current page` objects,

A new user will get items from the first page. While the user is scrolling through the listview, the list expands with items from the next page (and the next and the next etc.)

this is my response
http://pastie.org/10259792

The following is code I've tried:

HomeFragment

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
// Listview Adapter
        ListViewAdapter adapters;

            // Connection detector
            ConnectionDetector cd;

            // Alert dialog manager
            AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

            // Progress Dialog
            private ProgressDialog pDialog;

            // Creating JSON Parser object
            JSONparserr jsonParser = new JSONparserr();

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> WebsiteList;

            // albums JSONArray
            JSONArray data = null;
            String link_url;

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayTemplist;

            private AutoCompleteTextView inputSearch;

            private ListView lv;

            private static final String URL_ALBUMS = "";

            private static final String WEBSITE_MENU_ID ="Brand_name";

            private static final String TAG_MATCH="data";
            //private static final String TAG_NAME="Brand_name";
            private static final String TAG_PROFILE="id";
            private static final String TAG_CAST="Company";

public HomeFragment(){}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listpehlu);


    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getActivity());


    WebsiteList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

 // Loading Albums JSON in Background Thread
 new LoadAlbums().execute();

    // get listview

    inputSearch = (AutoCompleteTextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextViewhomefrag);

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

            arrayTemplist= new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
            String searchString =inputSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

            for (int i = 0; i < WebsiteList.size(); i++)
            {
                String currentString =WebsiteList.get(i).get(HomeFragment.this.WEBSITE_MENU_ID);
                if (currentString.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchString ))
                {
                    arrayTemplist.add(WebsiteList.get(i));
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayTemplist.size(); i++)
            {
                String currentstrin = arrayTemplist.get(i).get(HomeFragment.this.WEBSITE_MENU_ID);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), currentstrin, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
      SimpleAdapter adapters = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), arrayTemplist,R.layout.list_item_match, new String[] {WEBSITE_MENU_ID,TAG_CAST
            }, new int[] {
                    R.id.txtbrndnm,R.id.txtbrndcomp});
            lv.setAdapter(adapters);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                         
        }
    });


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                long arg3) {


            Selected_Product_Listing tf = new Selected_Product_Listing();
             Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
             bundle.putString("prducts_name", WebsiteList.get(position).get((WEBSITE_MENU_ID)));
            // bundle.putString("prducts_name", aList.get(position).get(INTEREST_ACCEPT_NAME));
             tf.setArguments(bundle);
              FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
              FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
              ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, tf);
              ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
              ft.addToBackStack(null);
              ft.commit();

            // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"lets"+ WebsiteList.get(position).get(convertToBase64(convertToBase64(WEBSITE_MENU_ID))), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });   

    lv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {


        }

        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        if(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount!=0)
        {

        }
        }
        });



    return rootView;
}

public String convertToBase64(String text) {
    byte[] data = null;
    try {
        data = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
}

class LoadAlbums extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private JSONObject jsonObj;


    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progress));

        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ALBUMS, "GET",
                params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("Albums JSON: ", "> " + json);
        if (json != null) {
            try {
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                // Getting JSON Array node
                data = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_MATCH);

                String totpage=jsonObj.getString("total_page");
                System.out.println("Total Page"+totpage);

                String curpage=jsonObj.getString("current_page");
                System.out.println("Total Page"+curpage);



                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(WEBSITE_MENU_ID,c.getString(WEBSITE_MENU_ID));
                 map.put(TAG_PROFILE, c.getString(TAG_PROFILE));
                    map.put(TAG_CAST, c.getString(TAG_CAST));

                    WebsiteList.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
       return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all albums
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        getActivity(), WebsiteList,
                        R.layout.list_item_match, new String[] {WEBSITE_MENU_ID,TAG_CAST
                         }, new int[] {
                                R.id.txtbrndnm,R.id.txtbrndcomp});


               lv.setAdapter(adapter); 

            }


    }
```

EndlessAdapter

```
 public class EndLessAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private Context context;
private List<String> items;
private int layoutId;

public EndLessAdapter(Context context, List<String> items, int LayoutId) {
    super(context,LayoutId,items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    this.layoutId = LayoutId;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null)
        convertView = ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(layoutId,parent,false);

    TextView tView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    tView.setText(items.get(position));

    return convertView;
}
 }
```

EndlessLisView

```
public class EndlessListView extends ListView implements OnScrollListener {

private Context context;
private View footer;
private boolean isLoading;
private EndLessListener listener;

private BaseAdapter  adapter;

public EndlessListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);        
    this.setOnScrollListener(this);

    this.context = context;
}

public EndlessListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setOnScrollListener(this);

    this.context = context;
}

public EndlessListView(Context context) {
    super(context);     
    this.setOnScrollListener(this);

    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

}   

//  4
public void addNewData() {
    this.removeFooterView(footer);
   //       adapter.addAll(products);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    isLoading = false;
}
public void setLoading()
{
    isLoading = false;
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    if(getAdapter() == null)
        return;

    if(getAdapter().getCount() == 0)
        return;

    int l = visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItem;
    System.out.println("List View Total Item Count = "+totalItemCount+" , l = "+l+", is_loading = "+isLoading);
    if(l >= totalItemCount && !isLoading){

        //  add footer layout
        this.addFooterView(footer);

        //  set progress boolean
        isLoading = true;
        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$ call loaddata $$$$$$$$$$$");
        //  call interface method to load new data
        listener.loadData();
    }
}

//  Calling order from MainActivity
//  1
public void setLoadingView(int resId) {

    footer = ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(resId, null);      //      footer = (View)inflater.inflate(resId, null);
    this.addFooterView(footer);
    System.out.println("addfooter ====@@@@@@");
}   

//  2
public void setListener(EndLessListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}   

//  3
public void setAdapter(BaseAdapter adapter) {       

    super.setAdapter(adapter);
    this.adapter = adapter;

    this.removeFooterView(footer);
}

public void removeFooter(){
    this.removeFooterView(footer);
}
```

}

Comment: so,whats your problem?what error you got?

Comment: getting error here app crash    listener.loadData();

Comment: look up the ViewHolder pattern

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i dint get you

Comment: @Roman What you're trying to implement is called lazy loading, or pagination. Could you please post the whole code handling this matter?

Comment: You need to post the whole exception with stacktrace. Please add it to the question and don't post it as a comment.

Comment: @DavidWasser need help

Comment: I can see why the app crash on listener.loadData(), The object listener is probably have null address! This object requires to be set.  And please just post the logcat error messages when/if your app crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didn't use EndlessListView in your Fragment. As I looked your response, it includes pagination. So, you need to request with page number to use endless scroll.

This is just flow for Endless Listview. If your code still doesn't work, I hope you can learn sample projects after read this messages. I added only parts you need. Thanks

> Endless scroll only shows limited data on listview. When user scroll down to bottom, it will get next limited data from server. So you need to add **current_page** paramater in your request. I don't know exactly your api.

First, you need variable for current_page which initialize with 0

You have to know when to stop. You response has **total_page** field for that. Save and add validation

Then you need to know when to request next page. For that,you already have codes in **onScroll** within EndlessListView. That code calculate and tell when user scroll down to bottom and it called

```
listener.loadData();
```

to request new data. But you still need to add listener for that. You already have

```
public void setListener(EndLessListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

> You need to create **Interface** with the name **EndlessListener** and implements in your fragment. EndlessListener Interface will include **loadData()** function that request to server. After that you need to add listener for the listview.

```
endlessListView.setListener(this);
```

Comment: what i am trying is...by default i am gettting data of currentpage 0,,and when user scrolls..it should load data of current page1

Comment: yes, you need to increase page after you request is success.

Comment: Which chat room? It's okay to help.

Comment: here in stackoverflow

Comment: @Roman, I think this post answers some of your problems. You already have the OnScroll listener in EndlessListView. I would think that is a somewhat easy fix. If you decide on using another library, as another suggest, which may work well, you may likely have to do some code redesign.

Comment: I upvote this answer because I think this is the correct path to the solution. I do not know how to be more elaborate than this mainly because of the lack of relevant specific code.

Comment: @HeinHtetAung http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782797/fragment-tabhost-is-not-working-in-fragment ..help me

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve this by using the following library in Github

https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/PagingListView

Simple create your `PagingAdapter` and add it to `com.paging.listview.PagingListView`.
You have to implements the new Pagingable interface and its `onLoadMoreItems()` method. For example:

```
listView.setHasMoreItems(true);
listView.setPagingableListener(new PagingListView.Pagingable() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadMoreItems() {
        if (pager < 3) {
            new CountryAsyncTask(false).execute();
        } else {
            listView.onFinishLoading(false, null);
        }
    }
});
```

Finally you can use the `onFinishLoading(boolean hasMoreItems, List newItems)` method to update the list.

```
listView.onFinishLoading(true, newItems);
```

Also remember to use this package in your layout files:

```
<com.paging.listview.PagingListView
    android:id="@+id/paging_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: can you tell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847086/how-to-attach-jpg-or-png-file-to-gmail-or-facebook

Comment: @roman :- you can have a look into the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847086/how-to-attach-jpg-or-png-file-to-gmail-or-facebook/31848852#31848852

Answer (score 4):

Hello here you can find the nostra library for lazy loading and then you can 
implement the following example for lazzy loading

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

you can achieve Lazy loading by using the below

code

Lets start the coding about the lazy loading.

```
MainActivity.java


    package com.sunil.lazyloading;


    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private Button btnlist=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnlist= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_listview);
        btnlist.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("stringarrayimage", Constants.IMAGES);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
CustomAdapter.java


    package com.sunil.adapter;

    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.List;

    import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
    import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
    import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageLoadingListener;
    import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.SimpleImageLoadingListener;
    import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.FadeInBitmapDisplayer;
    import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.RoundedBitmapDisplayer;
    import com.sunil.lazyloading.R;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;



public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private String imageurl[]=null;
    private Context context=null;
    DisplayImageOptions doption=null;
    private ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener =null;


    public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, String[] imageurl)
    {
        this.context=activity;
        this.imageurl=imageurl;
        doption=new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error).showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_stub).cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisc(true).displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20)).build();
        animateFirstListener = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageurl.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            view = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_list_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText("Item " + (position + 1));
        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.displayImage(imageurl[position], holder.image, doption, animateFirstListener);

        return view;
    }

    private static class AnimateFirstDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {

        static final List<string> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<string>());

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            if (loadedImage != null) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
                if (firstDisplay) {
                    FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                    displayedImages.add(imageUri);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
        public ImageView image;
    }
}
</string></string>
ImageListActivity.java

    package com.sunil.lazyloading;



        import java.util.Collections;
        import java.util.LinkedList;
        import java.util.List;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.graphics.Bitmap;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.ListView;

        import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
        import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.SimpleImageLoadingListener;
MainActivity.java


    package com.sunil.lazyloading;


    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private Button btnlist=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnlist= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_listview);
        btnlist.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("stringarrayimage", Constants.IMAGES);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
CustomAdapter.java


    package com.sunil.adapter;

    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.List;

    import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
    import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
    import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageLoadingListener;
    import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.SimpleImageLoadingListener;
    import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.FadeInBitmapDisplayer;
    import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.RoundedBitmapDisplayer;
    import com.sunil.lazyloading.R;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;



public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private String imageurl[]=null;
    private Context context=null;
    DisplayImageOptions doption=null;
    private ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener =null;


    public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, String[] imageurl)
    {
        this.context=activity;
        this.imageurl=imageurl;
        doption=new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error).showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_stub).cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisc(true).displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20)).build();
        animateFirstListener = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageurl.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            view = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_list_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText("Item " + (position + 1));
        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.displayImage(imageurl[position], holder.image, doption, animateFirstListener);

        return view;
    }

    private static class AnimateFirstDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {

        static final List<string> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<string>());

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            if (loadedImage != null) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
                if (firstDisplay) {
                    FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                    displayedImages.add(imageUri);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
        public ImageView image;
    }
}
</string></string>
ImageListActivity.java

    package com.sunil.lazyloading;



        import java.util.Collections;
        import java.util.LinkedList;
        import java.util.List;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.graphics.Bitmap;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.ListView;

        import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.FadeInBitmapDisplayer;
        import com.sunil.adapter.CustomAdapter;


public class ImageListActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

    private ListView listview=null;
    private String[] imageUrls;
    protected ImageLoader imageLoader=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.imagelist);

        listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_image);
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        imageUrls = bundle.getStringArray("stringarrayimage");
        CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(ImageListActivity.this, imageUrls);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImagePagerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("imageurlpostion", imageUrls);
        intent.putExtra("imagepostion", position);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AnimateFirstDisplayListener.displayedImages.clear();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }


    private static class AnimateFirstDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {

        static final List<string> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<string>());

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            if (loadedImage != null) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
                if (firstDisplay) {
                    FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                    displayedImages.add(imageUri);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item_clear_memory_cache:
                imageLoader.clearMemoryCache();
                return true;
            case R.id.item_clear_disc_cache:
                imageLoader.clearDiscCache();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<button android:id="@+id/button_listview" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="ListView ImageLoad">
```

imagelist.xml

```
<listview android:id="@+id/listView_image" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">
</listview>
```

item_list_row.xml

```
<imageview android:adjustviewbounds="true" android:contentdescription="@string/descr_image" android:id="@+id/image" android:layout_height="72dip" android:layout_margin="3dip" android:layout_width="72dip" android:scaletype="centerCrop">

<textview android:id="@+id/text" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginleft="20dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textsize="22sp">
```

**For the Example above you need to download the library universal image loader you can download the library ... happy coding :)**

Answer (score 1):

Try Loading data when listview reaches it's end. Implement OnScrollListener in your fragment. Refer this link [Android - ListView to load more items when reached end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458475/android-listview-to-load-more-items-when-reached-end)

Comment: getting null ponter exception at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.endless.EndlessListView.onScroll(EndlessListView.java:81)

Answer (score 1):

You **MUST** use [Paging 3 library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview) to resolve all problems in simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

**ListView XMl:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/orderlistview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**OrderList class**

```
public class OrderList {

    int _orderId;
    int _orderincrement_id;
    String _orderstatus;
    String _orderdate;
    String _ordership_to;
    String _ordertotal;
    String _ordercurrency_symbol;

    // Empty constructor
    public OrderList() {

    }

    // constructor
    public OrderList(int _orderId, int _orderincrement_id, String _orderstatus,
            String _orderdate, String _ordership_to, String _ordertotal,
            String _ordercurrency_symbol) {
        this._orderId = _orderId;
        this._orderincrement_id = _orderincrement_id;
        this._orderstatus = _orderstatus;
        this._orderdate = _orderdate;
        this._ordership_to = _ordership_to;
        this._ordertotal = _ordertotal;
        this._ordercurrency_symbol = _ordercurrency_symbol;

    }

    public int get_orderId() {
        return _orderId;
    }

    public void set_orderId(int _orderId) {
        this._orderId = _orderId;
    }

    public int get_orderincrement_id() {
        return _orderincrement_id;
    }

    public void set_orderincrement_id(int _orderincrement_id) {
        this._orderincrement_id = _orderincrement_id;
    }

    public String get_orderstatus() {
        return _orderstatus;
    }

    public void set_orderstatus(String _orderstatus) {
        this._orderstatus = _orderstatus;
    }

    public String get_orderdate() {
        return _orderdate;
    }

    public void set_orderdate(String _orderdate) {
        this._orderdate = _orderdate;
    }

    public String get_ordership_to() {
        return _ordership_to;
    }

    public void set_ordership_to(String _ordership_to) {
        this._ordership_to = _ordership_to;
    }

    public String get_ordertotal() {
        return _ordertotal;
    }

    public void set_ordertotal(String _ordertotal) {
        this._ordertotal = _ordertotal;
    }

    public String get_ordercurrency_symbol() {
        return _ordercurrency_symbol;
    }

    public void set_ordercurrency_symbol(String _ordercurrency_symbol) {
        this._ordercurrency_symbol = _ordercurrency_symbol;
    }

}
```

**Activity**

```
public class OrderListFragment extends Fragment {

    View rootView;
    ListView lv;
    List<OrderList> list ;
    MyListAdapter adt;
    DatabaseHandler db ;
    ProgressDialog progress;
    SharedPreferences pref;

    public OrderListFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentorderlist, container,
                false);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.orderlistview);


        db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
        list = db.getAllOrderList();
        if(list.size() == 0){
            progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progress.setMessage("Fetching Data.....");
            progress.setIndeterminate(true);
            progress.setCancelable(false);
            progress.show();

            pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

            String customer_id = pref.getString("customer_id", null);

            Log.v("log_tag", "customer_id"+customer_id);
            if(customer_id != null){
                Log.v("log_tag", "customer_id 2332 ::: "+customer_id);
                new FetchOrderListData().execute(customer_id);
            }
        }
        adt = new MyListAdapter(getActivity());
        lv.setAdapter(adt);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                        long id) {

                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("orderlist_increment_id", list.get(position).get_orderincrement_id()+"");
                    Fragment fragment = new OrderdetailFragment();
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = OrderListFragment.this
                            .getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                            .beginTransaction();
                    mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.Frame_Layout, fragment)
                            .commit();

                }
            });

        return rootView;
    }

    public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public MyListAdapter(Context context) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        }

        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_orderlistdata,
                    null);
            TextView ordernumbertxt = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.ordernumberTxt);
            TextView orderdate = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.orderdateTxt);
            TextView orderamount = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.orderAmountTxt);
            TextView orderSatusTxt = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.orderSatusTxt);

            ordernumbertxt.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Order Number : </b>"+list.get(position).get_orderincrement_id()+""));
            orderdate.setText(list.get(position).get_orderdate());
            orderSatusTxt.setText(list.get(position).get_orderstatus());
            String parts = list.get(position).get_ordertotal(); 

            double d = Double.parseDouble(parts);
            double dval = roundTwoDecimals(d);
            orderamount.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Total  : </b>"+list.get(position).get_ordercurrency_symbol()+" "+dval));

            return convertView;
        }

         public double roundTwoDecimals(double d) {
              DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
              return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
            }
    }

    private class FetchOrderListData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONObject listSize = null;

            Integer cust_id = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            try {
                listSize = DBAda.getAllOrderListData(cust_id);
                ////*** call your HTTP Service over here ***////
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return listSize;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObj) {
            db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
            if (progress != null) {
                progress.hide();
            }
            if (jsonObj == null) {

                return;
            }



            JSONArray json;

            try {
                json = jsonObj.getJSONArray("records");

                for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jobj;
                    try {
                        jobj = json.getJSONObject(i);
                        int order_id = Integer.parseInt(jobj.getString("order_id").toString());
                        int order_IncrementId = Integer.parseInt(jobj.getString("increment_id").toString());
                        String orderStatus = jobj.getString("status");
                        String orderdate = jobj.getString("date");
                        String ordershipto = jobj.getString("ship_to");
                        String ordertotal = jobj.getString("order_total");
                        String ordersymbol = jobj.getString("currency_symbol");

                        //db.addWishlistItem(new WishList(entity_id,quentity,comment,name,short_description,thumbnails,itemId));

                        db.addOrderListItem(new OrderList(order_id, order_IncrementId, orderStatus, orderdate, ordershipto, ordertotal, ordersymbol));



                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.orderlistview);


            db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
            list = db.getAllOrderList();
            adt = new MyListAdapter(getActivity());
            lv.setAdapter(adt);

        }
    }


}
```